# exclude timestamps depending of a sub-timestamp (postgresql)

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, where-clause

I have data that looks like this:

```
 ID     | timespan
 ------ | ------
 1      | 12 days 23:45:00 
 2      | 02:45:00 
 3      | 23:45:00 
 4      | 10 days 03:30:00
```

I want to exclude every timespan which includes 23:45:00
so I that get this output

```
 ID     | timespan
 ------ | ------
 2      | 02:45:00 
 4      | 10 days 03:30:00
```

How should I write the where clause?

Comment: What data type is `timespan`?

Comment: the data type of 'timespan' is 'interval'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with data(id, timespan) as (
values
    ( 1, '12 days 23:45:00'::interval),
    ( 2, '02:45:00'), 
    ( 3, '23:45:00'), 
    ( 4, '10 days 03:30:00')
)
select *
from data
where timespan::text like '%23:45:00%';
```